# How to resize images at a 4D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, image-resizing

I have a 4D numpy array which stores 50 slices of 100*100 images. So I want to use them in order to train 3d Resnet CNN. How can I resize the images for Resnet Input?

the original shape is:

```
data.shape

(50, 128, 100, 100)
```

the target shape is:

```
(50, 128, 96, 96)
```

and the input is:

```
model = Resnet3DBuilder.build_resnet_18((128, 96, 96, 1), 20)

slice = 128
img size = 96*96*1
classes = 20
```

Comment: @kmario23 i added the information you want

Comment: So, IIUC, you wish to resize `(50, 128, 100, 100)` to `(50, 128, 96, 96)` right?

Comment: @kmario23 yes '(50, 128, 96, 96)' is my target

Comment: You can use: `resized_data = np.resize(data, (50, 128, 96, 96))`; Please note that this will truncate the extra data which doesn't fit the shape

Comment: @kmario23 although it works, the image is changed

Comment: Since we're throwing away some of the pixels, this is expected..